# Behat 3 - passing parameters (from imported file) to FeatureContext constructor

Tags: php, yaml, behat

I'm fairly new to Behat and YAML, and I'm having trouble passing large arrays of parameters to the FeatureContext constructor.

With Behat 2, the following worked fine:

behat.yml (shortened for convenience):

```
default:
  context:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://mysite.local'
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
      ...
imports:
    - config/data/mydata.yml
```

and mydata.yml:

```
default:
  context:
    parameters:
      some_long_array:
        'key1': 'value1'
        'key2': 'value2'
        ...
```

and I could have many such imported parameter files.

Using Behat 3 - I tried to achieve the same thing with the following
behat.yml (shortened):

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://mysite.local'
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
  ...
imports:
    - config/data/mydata.yml
```

and mydata.yml:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
            parameters:
              some_long_array:
                'key1': 'value1'
                'key2': 'value2'
                ...
```

This does not work and nothing gets passed to the constructor.

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   FeatureContext::__construct() must be of the type array, none given in
>   FeatureContext->__construct()

My FeatureContext class looks like this:

```
class FeatureContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext
{

  /**
   * Initializes context.
   *
   * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
   * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
   * context constructor through behat.yml.
   */
  public function __construct(array $parameters)
  {
    var_dump($parameters);
  }

}
```

If I pass the parameters inline in behat.yml (instead of in an imported file), everything works ok:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext:
            parameters:
              some_long_array:
                'key1': 'value1'
                'key2': 'value2'
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://mysite.local'
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
  ...
```

and the tests run and I can see the array as expected. The problem is that I have several large parameter arrays and it would be impractical to specify them all in the behat.yml file.

How can I specify large parameter arrays in external files using Behat 3?

Comment: Have you found any solution to what you were trying to do? I'm facing the same issue and could not find anything suitable for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You were so close man. I was able to do it this way:

```
default:
    autoload: [ %paths.base%/contexts ]
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://qa.api.somesite.com
            sessions:
                default:
                    selenium2: ~
        Sanpi\Behatch\Extension: ~
    suites:
        default:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features ]
            filters:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
        frontend:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/frontend ]
            filters:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                    parameters:
                        environment: qa
                        api_url: http://api.somesite.com
                        login: some_login
                        key: 409jfa94k4tj
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
                - behatch:browser
```

If you notice under the "frontend" suite I have the context "FeatureContext". Below that is the name of the parameter that the constructor for the FeatureContext class will be expecting. Then it automatically turns it into an associative array.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the function definition has to use the same parameter name as given in the behat.yml file.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't seem to user `imports` though. Is this still possible in behat 3.1.0? I'd like to have a 'base' behat.yml file which imports a config.yml file which contains items like the api_url, login, key, etc. This means the behat.yml file can be version controlled, and the config.yml can be environment specific.

Comment: @RichardTape does a solution for the import exist? I am facing the same problem right now, if there isn't a solution I would write my own extension to make it possible

Comment: If there is a solution, I haven't found it yet @EmilioMg -- please, please report back if you find one :)

Comment: I remember in Behat 2 I was able to reference other YML files. But I haven't tried in Behat 3 and I have been away from the job where I worked with Behat for a year and a half now. So I don't even have access to my old code.

Comment: @RichardTape The `imports` @smrkem wrote in his question works fine in Behat v3. You have a `behat.yml` that contains all the static config, and at the top of the `behat.yml` you have a `imports:\n\t - config/config.yml` (with newline and tab). This file is in the `.gitignore` and is a clone of the `behat.yml` regarding the config keys and nestings, but it contains only the environment configs like urls, paths, api-keys etc. This works fine for me. I also made a config.yml.dist with a default/demo config which I checked into the git repo.

Comment: 2 things: make sure that you have proper indentation for `parameters` under `- FeatureContext:` and make sure you regenerate composer autoload classes `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @EmilioMg OK I'm clearly being very stupid then, I just can't get it to work at all. I've tried the following: https://gist.github.com/richardtape/46b38590d04b04f03aa690f52d9a5853 but nothing seems to work. I either get errors as described in that gist or the value is never overridden. Any chance you can provide a concrete example of this working?